# iOS Image search on the web

Tags: ios, image, search, web

I am developing the functionality of letting the user search the internet for images through any query.

There are services/APIs like Google's (I read that it is deprecated), Yahoo and Bing etc. I want to know, is there any `FREE` services/APIs/frameworks/libraries for iOS to search for images against any query?

We can fetch the thumbnails against the results URL and populate a grid-view to show the thumbnails. Then download the actual image in the App once the user clicks on a particular image. Is there any such service that is free?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use flickr, in the [Ray Wenderlich site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) you have a good tutorial of how to use it. About the services you mentions I don't know if the has a public (free) API